# Best way to Drag an object off screen and immediately reappear - Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Im trying to figure out the best approach to drag an object off towards the side and have it immediately reappear the other end almost as if its one super large image that you are dragging.

I have the drag controls set up so that they are moving along an entire display.group but don't know roughly the right way to do this part.

**Here is my Drag function**

```
local baseGroup = display.newGroup()

function dragPlayer(e)
if gameIsActive == true then
    if(e.phase == 'began') then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(baseGroup)
        lastX = e.x - baseGroup.x
        --print("DRAG")
    elseif(e.phase == 'moved') then
        baseGroup.x = e.x - lastX
    elseif(e.phase == 'ended') then 
        --print(player.x)
        --onScreenTouch()
    end
end
end

baseGroup:addEventListener("touch", dragPlayer)
```

Comment: As in, you want it to wrap around the screen? Like a game of Pacman? Or something else?

Comment: Yes exactly, just like pacman. Almost as seamless so that you cannot notice its looping.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is usually called an "infinity background" or a "scrolling background." Here are a few guides to help you, and the first one even has help on designing the image itself: [1](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/corona-sdk-creating-a-scrolling-background--mobile-6668) [2](http://www.webdevils.com/corona-sdk-scrolling-landscape/).

Here is a simple little block that works with a single image:

```
local landscape = display.newImageRect( "landscape-1.png", 1440, 320 )

-- landscape:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint ) landscape_1.anchorX = 0 landscape_1.anchorY = 0 landscape_1.x = 0 landscape_1.y = 0

local function reset_landscape( landscape )     landscape.x = 0     transition.to( landscape, {x=0-1440+480, time=30000, onComplete=reset_landscape} ) end

reset_landscape( landscape_1 )
```

This one is more complex and allows you to be a bit more tricky in your design:

```
local function make_landscape( image, width, height, time )
    local landscape = display.newImageRect( image, width, height )

    -- landscape:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint )
    landscape.anchorX = 0
    landscape.anchorY = 0   
    landscape.x = 0
    landscape.y = 320 - height
    landscape.time = time

    local function reset_landscape( landscape )
        landscape.x = 0
        transition.to( landscape, {x=0-landscape.width+480, time=landscape.time, onComplete=reset_landscape} )
    end

    reset_landscape( landscape )

    return landscape
end 

local landscape_group = display.newGroup()

local landscape_1 = make_landscape( "Landscape-1.png", 1440, 86, 10000 )
local landscape_2 = make_landscape( "Landscape-2.png", 1440, 168, 20000 )
local landscape_3 = make_landscape( "Landscape-3.png", 1440, 215, 30000 )

landscape_group:insert( landscape_3 )
landscape_group:insert( landscape_2 )
landscape_group:insert( landscape_1 )
```

You'll have to customize as needed, of course. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help kirkpatt but I I'm not looking to use transitions and stuff. For my particular game I can drag an object of screen and would like it to wrap around to the other end.

Comment: @DipeshDhanji Okay, sorry about that. You want to wrap the game environment itself, not just the background. I'm going to leave that answer up in case anyone else finds this, but I'll poke around to see what I can find for objects themselves.

Comment: Thats ok mate. Yeah just a few graphics inside a display group. Ive edited the post above to show my drag control

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is another way that allows 1 object being wrapped around the boarders. I guess not.

One approach I would think of is creating a copy of your object as soon as it starts to cross one boarder. This copy will then come from the other boarder, doing the exact same movements as the original object.
One of them leaving the screen will lead to its destruction so you again have only one object. Implementation should be pretty straight forward and simple.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. How would you go about setting that up? I haven't set up anything similar where I create clones before. Let's say I had blue, red, green objects that hold specific parameters for collision, how would I set it up so that the clone has that too?

Comment: @DipeshDhanji I'm no Corona expert. You should find out if there is an official way to copy display objects and like a getCopy function or so and use it. If not you should implement a function that copies them by creating a new display object and copying all properties from the original one ( all but the position of course).

Comment: no worries mate, thanks for the suggestions on ways to get this working. I should be able to get something working from this